# Snort or Suricata whilst using Docker?

Tags: security, containers, microservices, snort, suricata

Guess I am going to use multiple docker files for my **IDS/IPS** - using microservice. Say more than 50 *docker* containers for it.
Would you use *Suricata* or *Snort*? Is it really important that Snort is not *multithread*, and does it snort *weaker* than Suricata??

Answer (score 0):

Use Docker from dtag-dev-sev

https://github.com/dtag-dev-sec/suricata

dockerized suricata

suricata is a Network IDS, IPS and Network Security Monitoring engine.

This repository contains the necessary files to create a dockerized version of suricata.